# Query regarding Oracle index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have two tables created in an Oracle DB and I am using them in queries something like given below. One table has index and the other table doesn't

```
    select * from (
    select * from table_with_an_index
    union all
    select * from table_without_an_index
    )first_table
    join second_table 
   where first_table.index_col=second_table.col
```

My question is that, in the above query, the index of the first table will be used? Or will it store records from both the tables first in memory and then apply filter without using index of the first table?

I searched about this in the internet and I am not able to get a correct answer. Any clue would be appreciated

Comment: Please give a reason also, people who are voting down

Comment: i dont think any index will be used if the only table that has an index(table_with_an_index) gets a select *

Comment: if you want to use the index, make the join first and then the union. But performances here depends also on each table number of lines.

Comment: thanks Lorenzo and Steven for your inputs

Comment: take a look ad EXPLAIN PLAN

Answer (score 1):

In this case CBO likely to do 2 full scans, then union then hash join.

If second table is small, few values, and access small percentage of table_with_an_index, then, probably, CBO will push predicate and do index access union with full scan and then nested loops.

Index access is not always fastest